# Existe alguma workflow, no git, onde se determina o acesso e o bloqueio de arquivos?

Tags: git, github

Sobre o Git, teria alguma forma onde cada usuário determina quais arquivos e por quanto tempo, o outro usuário terá acesso a edição de determinados arquivos, queria alguma forma onde se evite os conflitos dos arquivos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, pois o Git é um [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control). Ou seja, o usuário sempre terá uma cópia do repositório, que está desconectado de qualquer server, sendo assim, não seria possível controlar políticas locais de acesso a arquivos. Pois o objetivo de um repositório DVCS é ser um repositório central, caso precise.
Se você precisa controlar esse tipo de coisa o melhor seria usar um CVCS, por exemplo: TFVC, do Team Foudation Server; Subversion (SVN), ...
Porém eu analisaria a real necessidade desse bloqueio. Seria possível resolver esse problema, via processo. Quando um desenvolvedor requisitar um PR para um repositório central, uma pessoa no papel de integrador de código, faria o aceite ou recusaria.

Answer (score 1):

Não. A melhor forma de controlar a edição de arquivos de uma forma democrática no git é usar pull requests. Veja se [esse material](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) te ajuda por gentileza